# Javascript object : select the whole object that has known key : value pair

Tags: javascript, json

I'm confused with a complex json object, in the example bellow, how can I store in a variable the whole object that has `entreprise : 'microsoft'`.

```
clientList = {
    id-1111 : {
        entreprise : 'facebook',
        president : 'Mark',
    },
    id-2222 : {
        entreprise : 'microsoft',
        president : 'Bill',
    },
    id-3333 : {
        entreprise : 'apple',
        president : 'Tim'
    }
}
```

I dynamicly get, for axample, 'Microsoft', and I would like to obtain as output :

```
{
    entreprise : 'microsoft',
    president : 'Bill'
}
```

I know it is a basic question, but I'm struggling with that for hours.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Well reference it by the keys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `find` to find a single item from a list.

```js
var clientList = {
    "id-1111": {
        entreprise : 'facebook',
        president : 'Mark',
    },
    "id-2222" : {
        entreprise : 'microsoft',
        president : 'Bill',
    },
    "id-3333" : {
        entreprise : 'apple',
        president : 'Tim'
    }
};
var result = Object.values(clientList).find(x => x.entreprise == "microsoft");
console.log(result);
```

Comment: should be === identity match for the find function

Answer (score 3):

To find all objects with a paticular enterprise, use `Array.filter`:

```js
const clientList = {
    "id-1111" : {
        entreprise : 'facebook',
        president : 'Mark',
    },
    "id-2222" : {
        entreprise : 'microsoft',
        president : 'Bill',
    },
    "id-3333" : {
        entreprise : 'apple',
        president : 'Tim'
    }
};

function findClientsByEnterprise(enterprise) {
  return Object.values(clientList).filter( i => i.entreprise === enterprise);
}

console.log(findClientsByEnterprise("microsoft"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your object has broken. Use quote in your object key.

```js
clientList = {
    'id-1111' : {
        entreprise : 'facebook',
        president : 'Mark',
    },
    'id-2222' : {
        entreprise : 'microsoft',
        president : 'Bill',
    },
    'id-3333' : {
        entreprise : 'apple',
        president : 'Tim'
    }
};

function objectSearch(key, value,obj){
 for(o in obj){
  if(obj[o][key] == value){
   return obj[o];
  }
 }
  
  return {};
}

console.log(objectSearch('entreprise','microsoft',clientList));
```

Answer (score -1):

if the enterprise can be used as a unique ID, you could just use it as such:

```
'microsft': {
    enterprise: 'microsoft',
    president: 'Bill'
}
```

but as a general rule, it is not a great practice to do this. So maintaining a structure with a list of objects with unique ID's and using find would be the best solution and best practice:

```
clientList = [
    {
        id: 'id-1111',
        entreprise : 'facebook',
        president : 'Mark',
    },
    {
        id: 'id-2222',
        entreprise : 'microsoft',
        president : 'Bill',
    },
    {
        id: 'id-3333',
        entreprise : 'apple',
        president : 'Tim'
    }
}


const result = clientList.find(clientObj => clientObj.enterprise === "microsoft");
```